# better way spread scss variables to every scss file

Tags: node.js, sass

I created a global `scss` variable file in my root folder
and for import variables I wrtie
`@import  '../../../style_config/style_config'` (global variable file)
to every scss file

More i work in a deep folder hard to find Relative path
Is there any way to use absolute path ?  or better way import scss file?

#### Env

Create React App on node.js

#### Tried

- 1.Import scss variable file at index.js but scss file give me error.
  there is no variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code structure is:

```
app
  |_ config/webpack.config.js
  |_ src/assets/styles/_common.scss
```

In my **_common.scss** I have all my variables and mixins.

You need to set alias for your scss files in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      styles: path.join(__dirname, "../src/assets/styles")
    }
  }
}
```

and while importing the styles use `~`

```
@import "~styles/common";
```

**P.S:** I've been doing the exact same what you are doing now since a long time and have never thought it could be optimised. Thanks for putting this up.